# Equation of circle in 3D when 3 points are given

Tags: analytic-geometry, spheres

I need to find out the equation of circle having three points $$(a,0,0), (0,b,0), (0,0,c)$$.

I know that this represent when sphere is intersected by a plane. I can find the equation of plane using these planes by it's intercept form $$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$$, but how to find equation of sphere using 3 points only. Please suggest.

Comment: There can be multiple spheres that pass through those $3$ points. In general, you need $4$ non-coplanar points to define a sphere uniquely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative method:

The bisector plane of the first two points is given by
$$(x-a)^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+(y-b)^2+z^2$$
That is,
$$2ax-2by=a^2-b^2$$
Do the same for other bisector plane, for example $2ax-2cy=a^2-c^2$.

Find the intersection of these two planes and $x/a+y/b+z/c=1$. This is the center of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

A completion on @ajotatxe answer:

The bisector plane of the first two points is given by
$$(x-a)^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+(y-b)^2+z^2$$
That is,
$$2ax-2by=a^2-b^2$$
Do the same for other bisector plane, for example $2ax-2cz=a^2-c^2$.

Do the same for last bisector plane, $2by-2cz=b^2-c^2$.

Although two of them is enough.

Find the intersection of selected two planes and $x/a+y/b+z/c=1$.

This is the center of the circle.

Then the radius can be computed from this formula:
$$R = \frac{\alpha \beta \gamma}{2S}$$
Where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are edges lenght and $S$ is the area of triangle that can be computed from Heron's formula:
$$S^2=p(p-\alpha)(p-\beta)(p-\gamma)$$
Where $p$ is the half of perimeter:
$$p=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{2}$$
In this example edges lenghts are $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \sqrt{a^2+c^2}, \sqrt{b^2+c^2}$